# PyTorch GAN RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 0

Tags: python, pytorch

My data contains 120 JPEG images. When I want to train my model an error occurs. But when I use one of torchvision.datasets instead of my It works well.

```
batchSize = 64
imageSize = 64

transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(imageSize),transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),])

dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root = './input/',  transform = transform)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = batchSize,shuffle=True, num_workers = 1)
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 79, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 55, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Got 64 and 65 in dimension 2 at C:\w\1\s\tmp_conda_3.7_100118\conda\conda-bld\pytorch_1579082551706\work\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensor.cpp:612
```

Comment: Try printing out the shape of your tensor. There's probably some problem with the resizing (since it says got 64 and 65 even when you're resizing to 64).

Comment: @akshayk07 I printed out the shapes, and there are the first six: [3, 64, 64], [3, 84, 64], [3, 84, 64], [3, 64, 79], [3, 64, 79], [3, 64, 64]  But I still don't know why they have different dimensions.

Comment: Check the documentation of [torchvision.Resize](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize). It says that if you give an integer as the size, then it will resize the smaller side to the given size and the other side will be scaled to preserve the aspect ratio. Thus, your images might by default not have square images. So, it might be better to give (64, 64) as the size to the transform.